# How to only display title of post on blogspot homepage

Tags: html, css, blogger

Really sorry if this is the wrong place to post this but title.

[image: problem]

Am trying to only show the title ('Test') and the date uploaded. Not the body of text or the image.

Have tried looking for the HTML editor but I can't find one specifically for the home page. And I don't want to just add loads of spaces, this doesn't deal with the image problem.

Have tried copy and pasting this into the add css part of theme editor with no visible result:

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType in {&quot;static_page&quot;,&quot;item&quot;}'>

    //<div class='post-body entry-content' ...>

    //</div>
</b:if>
```

Am really grateful for any help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add the html code through blogger themes editor section 'Add CSS'. That is not fair because that section is only built for the adding the additional CSS to theme/template without editing actually HTML Template.

You can use the CSS code to solve your problem.

```
.post-body, .entry-content{
display: none;
}
```

This will hide the post body which contains the thumbnail and post snippets. But It will hide you page, post-page article also same home page. Do you need to add this with b:if condition where you hide one for homepage (index).

You have used:
Your question ❓ was about homepage so you should use `cond='data:blog pageType == "'index"'` instead of this one below  piece of your code.

`index' pageType include your Homepage, Search, Archive page in its self.

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType in {&quot;static_page&quot;,&quot;item&quot;}'>

    //<div class='post-body entry-content' ...>

    //</div>
</b:if>
```

**Another way**, find data:post.body/ wrap it with b:if condition according your requirement.